# How to check multiple roles discord.js v12

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm very new/bad at discord js. But I want to make a command with "allowed roles" so only admin, owner and mod can use it. But I don't know how.

I have tried this:

```
client.on('message', message => {
 if(message.content === 'test') {
 let allowedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "owner");
let allowedRole1 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "mod");
let allowedRole2 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "admin");
if (message.member.roles.cache.has(allowedRole.id) && message.member.roles.cache.has(allowedRole1.id) && message.member.roles.cache.has(allowedRole2.id)) {
message.channel.send('hello');
} else { 
   message.channel.send('bad');
}
}});
```

Comment: What happens instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your example, only users with all three roles are accepted (due to the [logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) operator).

Replace [`&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) with [`||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) and it should work as expected.

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.content === 'test') {
    let allowedRole = await message.guild.roles.cache.find(
      r => r.name === 'owner'
    );
    let allowedRole1 = await message.guild.roles.cache.find(
      r => r.name === 'mod'
    );
    let allowedRole2 = await message.guild.roles.cache.find(
      r => r.name === 'admin'
    );

    if (
      message.member.roles.cache.has(allowedRole.id) ||
      message.member.roles.cache.has(allowedRole1.id) ||
      message.member.roles.cache.has(allowedRole2.id)
    ) {
      message.channel.send('hello');
    } else {
      message.channel.send('bad');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It worked for a little while. But now it says this: cannot read property 'id' of undefined. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Latepate I made one more change. It might be, that the roles can not be fetched in time. a simple await call should fix that.

Comment: I tried to make async function because await can be only used in async function. But it didn't work :( So can you give me full code to save time?

Comment: This is the full code in the given scope you provided. If you need more, provide more Code. I can't help you with no knowledge of your existing Code

Comment: I don't know why it didn't show it but I edited it so now you can see it.

Comment: I changed my answer now too

Answer (score 1):

As Christoph said, you can use their code but I'd recommend to use role IDs intead because role name can be changed at any time:

```js
if (!message.member.roles.cache.has(<1st_role_id>) || !message.member.roles.cache.has(<2nd_role_id>) || !message.member.roles.cache.has(<3rd_role_id>)) 
return message.reply("You can't execute this command!")
// your code
```

## WARNING

It's only a solution if you are running private bot and not public, which is for a lot of servers